# PubSubHubBub Hubs

Tags: google-app-engine, push, websub

I'm currently building a live web application based upon the PubSubHubBub protocol. However, I encountered several issues.

First, I'm in search of a hub application that I can run on my server. There are several applications, but most of them are not mature yet, or they don't support the 0.3 spec. The official google hub runs on the Google App Engine and can even be executed locally. Unfortunately, `"Tasks will not run automatically. Push the 'Run' button to execute each task."`  This behaviour is useful for debugging and understanding the workflow, but in some live tests, it would be nice not to invoke all tasks manually. Is there a way to tweak the local app engine due automatically run tasks?

Next, I have a question concerning the spec itself. The Google reference implementation provides the initial publish method bound to the outpoint uri + `/publish`. But this is not reflected in the specs.

So are there any mature hubs that can be run locally for debugging? Or are there ways to configure the offical google app engine hub to run locally and to execute tasks directly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new 1.3.4 App Engine SDK automatically runs tasks. Just upgrade your SDK to take advantage of it.

```
Next, I have a question concerning the spec itself. The Google reference implementation provides the initial publish method bound to the outpoint uri + /publish. But this is not reflected in the specs.
```

/publish is the only endpoint provided by the hub. As per the [discovery section of the spec](http://pubsubhubbub.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pubsubhubbub-core-0.3.html#discovery), that is the one you advertise.

Comment: I'm already using version 1.3.4. Can the application override this flag?

Comment: No. It's possible you're setting an ETA - check if your tasks have ETAs in the future on the admin console - or that you're still running the old SDK despite having installed the new one.

Comment: Ok, that was a weird thing. It was caused by the wrong python version. When using 2.6, the tasks were not executed automatically, but manually still worked. After downgrading to 2.5, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/PubSubHubbub/wiki/Hubs lists all currently known hubs and software.

I also made my own hub that implements the 0.4 spec; see https://github.com/cweiske/phubb