# PHP Pubsubhubbub server

Tags: php, websub

I'm looking for a standalone Pubsubhubbub server written in PHP that I can use to test pubsubhubbub implementations locally without internet access.

I know about [PubSubHubBub Hubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027969/pubsubhubbub-hubs) and the [official hub list](https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/PubSubHubbub/wiki/Hubs), but there is no PHP-based hub in sight. Did I miss one? Which?

It seems that Zend Framework has some server code, but that's only a lib and no server that can be used out of the box.

Comment: :) such naming for a product almost deserves a darwin award.

Comment: http://github.com/cweiske/phpPubsubhubbub :-)

Comment: April Fools was 10 days ago, right?

Comment: @JoostK: Till knows that I like to hack and just wanted to encourage me to start a PuSH hub myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Phubb

Since 2015-04-01 I'm using my own, self-written and self-hosted PubSubHubbub server called "phubb".

https://github.com/cweiske/phubb

## Wordpress

The [PuSHPress Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pushpress/) not only implements the publisher side in Wordpress but also [the hub part](http://josephscott.org/archives/2010/03/pushpress-a-pubsubhubbub-plugin-for-wordpress/).
It should be able to use it as hub for other pages, too - with a little bit of hacking since

> To help keep things simple and limit potential abuse ...[it] will only allow subscriptions ..[of] of the WordPress blog that it is installed on.

Installing Wordpress locally is done in 5 minutes, and using the plugin shouldn't be that hard.

Edit: Yes, that one is on the official hub list and I originally dismissed it since it's not a standalone server, but hey, there doesn't seem to be more.

## Drupal

As of 2011-07, there is a [drupal module implementing a PuSH hub](https://github.com/lxbarth/osso/tree/master-2/profiles/osso_provider/modules/push_hub/).

Comment: [PuSHPress Wordpress plugin SVN Repository](http://svn.wp-plugins.org/pushpress/trunk/)

Comment: I hate to assign the bounty to my own answer, but after a week there was no better one, and I didn't want to get the points lost :/

Comment: Great find, regardless. Did you manage to extract it? I'd be interested in a php hub as well. Let me know if I can help.

Comment: @cweiske newbie needs help, and all links lead to you. :) Couldn't find any live copy of the reference py implementation of hub server. Would you have a copy of the original ref implementation? Or is PuSH already something of the past? If there's nothing, I can write a JS server that runs on docker, as I dont know PHP and need to customize quite a bit - some pointers will be great!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there only seems to be one implementation of the Pubsubhubhub protocol. That's the Google App Engine implementation.

Here's a slideshow going through the construction process of it if you're interested in creating another implementation: http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/BuildingAHub

Comment: The official hub list tells you that there is more than one implementation.

Comment: Can't locate this GAE implementation - looks like it  has been taken off the internet entirely! Any clue? Also, the code.google links for PuSH no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

StatusNet (http://status.net/) also implements a hub internally, but it's not available for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use http://superfeedr.com/. We host most of the hubs out there. It's often easier to use existing solutions than re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: "... that I can use to test pubsubhubbub implementations locally without internet access." Also, competition is not bad.

Comment: Gah! Sorry I overlooked the "local" part. If anyone ever finds this thread, using stuff like localtunnel (http://localtunnel.com/) helps setup things. As for competition : of course! I was just trying to be helpful as most people who use PubSubHubbub don't necessarily have to compete with hub providers :D